# Python3 - defining variable, function not executing -Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a declared a function:

```
def ec_msg(im,me):
    print('called!')    
    #do some processing 
    return im
```

which modifies a Pillow Image , but it's not executing(not even that print statement).
It's called later:
'im' and 'me' are already defined/loaded, not null:

```
im = ec_msg(im,me)
```

the im variable is NULL, because trying:

```
im.save("bla.png","PNG")
```

results in an error, saying im doesn't have a function called 'save'

EDIT:
More complete example:

```
from PIL import Image
import sys,os
def ec_msg(im,me):
    print('called!')    
    #do some processing like:
    im.putpixel((0,0),(255,255,255))
    return im

im = Image.open("cat.png")
me = open("abc.txt","r")
im = ec_msg(im,me)
im.save("cat1.png","PNG")
```

Comment: Is there a return somewhere earlier in that function, for example if there is an error?

Comment: protip: learn to use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Comment: What's `NULL`? Do you mean `None`? If the `print('called!') ` isn't printing, then `ec_msg` isn't being called, so we need to see more code to diagnose this problem. It would help if you posted a [mcve].

Comment: no, there's not. And the print command is the first one in the function, at it doesn't get run either.

Comment: Your example does not show where the variable `me` is defined.